# client template button event not firing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to display a pop up window when a user clicks on a button but I cant seem to get this to work. I can fire the event when using a custom command but I need a textbox and button next to each other in the same column.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("gridPopup")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName).Width(120);

    columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("").Width(110).ClientTemplate(
        Html.Kendo().TextBox()
        .Name("search_textfield")
        .Value("").ToClientTemplate().ToString()
        + " " +
        Html.Kendo().Button()
        .Name("search_button")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
        .Events(e =>
            e.Click("SearchButton")
        )
        .Content("...").ToClientTemplate().ToString()
    );
})

.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Pageable()
.Scrollable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:320px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
        model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(true);
        model.Field(p => p.CategoryID).DefaultValue(1);
    })

    .Read(read => read.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Read", "Home"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Update", "Home"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Create", "Home"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Destroy", "Home"))

)
)

<script type="text/javascript">


    function errorHandler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    function SearchButton(e)
    {
        alert("Search Button Clicked");
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird! `.Events(e => e.Click("SearchButton"))` is not generating the onclick attribute if used inside a ClientTemplate()

Try this, it will work for you, but i will wait for someone to explain it :)

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary", onclick = "SearchButton()" })
```

**Edit**:
The explanation that I found is here: [How do I use a Kendo UI widget inside a Grid client column template?](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-a-kendo-ui-widget-inside-a-grid-client-column-template). It says `script tags are not automatically evaluated inside a Grid client column template, so any included widgets will not be initialized.`

Therefore initializing the nested controls in `.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDatabound"))`

```
function onDatabound()
{
    jQuery("#gridPopup tbody [class='k-primary']").each(function () {
        $(this).kendoButton({ "click": SearchButton });
    })
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer once someone explains it.

Comment: Changed the edit mode from incell to  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)) and the event fired.